# Why does Getting a record, modifying its primary key, and then Putting it back seem to overwrite the record if the primary keys are different?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, unique-constraint

I have some confusion regarding the behavior of DynamoDB when writing a record.

Before describing my question, I should establish my understanding of how it all works. Please indicate if I'm misunderstanding something.

- When Putting an item into a table that already exists in the table, DynamoDB will "overwrite" (delete the existing record and write the new one) so as to avoid duplicates
- DynamoDB will overwrite a record if the incoming record's primary key matches that of an existing one in the table. For example, `{ primaryKey: "hey", otherAttribute: "yo" }` will overwrite `{ primaryKey: "hey", otherAttribute: "sup" }` because their primary keys match
- There are no uniqueness
- If I have an API that gets a record from a table, modifies the records attributes *including changing its primary key value to something new and unique*, and subsequently Puts it back into the table, it would be considered a new unique record and not overwrite the original retrieved record. It would essentially be a new record that matches an existing record except for the modified attributes and primary key.

As for my situation:

I have a Lambda being hit daily on a cronjob that gets a record from a table, modifies its primary key along with some other attributes, and Puts it back into the same table. However, while I am able to verify in the actual table that the new record has been inserted, I am unable to find the original record that was retrieved by the cronjob.

It appears instead that the record was pulled from the table, was modified by my Lambda, and then was Put back into the same table **overwriting the original record**.

But as far as I can tell that shouldn't happen, because their primary keys differ and for all intents and purposes are non-matching, according to DynamoDB.

**Why does retrieving a record, modifying its primary key, and re-inserting it to the table overwrite the record if the primary key is different? Is there something that's informing DynamoDB that this incoming record is "the same" as the one that was retrieved, despite having different primary keys?**

I will provide clarification on my situation if requested.

Comment: Maybe your code is at fault. Can you test with and provide [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) replicating the issue you have in the main codebase?

Comment: Can you share the relevant code from the lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an explanation for the behavior.

**DynamoDB's behavior is consistent, as expected.**

The records were indeed being submitted as duplicates, but the originals were not showing up in my date-indexed queries due to the date formats not being valid (which is one of the things needing fixed that led to this question in the first place).

Mystery solved - clean your data, people

Answer (score 2):

As the comments indicate, a minimal working example would be nice, so I'm working off of assumptions here.

At the core, DynamoDB has absolutely no concept of tracking the identity of an item outside of the primary key of that item in that table. So in other words, DynamoDB doesn't really "know" that what you attempt to put is "actually" another record that you fetched earlier. It just looks at the primary key provided, and will create or update an item in the table accordingly.

If this does not seem to reflect your code, maybe it's an issue with indirection? If you have an ORM layer or something like that sitting between DynamoDB and you, maybe changing the primary key in your code doesn't actually change it under the hood, due to change tracking mechanisms in the ORM you use?